# MySQL NOT IN with condition

Tags: php, mysql

I need to write a query that will pull all pieces of hardware that are unassigned to a user. My tables that look like this:

**table: hardware**
ID, brand, date_of_purchase, purchase_price, serial_number, invoice_location

**table: assigned_equipment**
ID, user_id, object_id, object_type, is_assigned, date_assigned

Once a piece of hardware is checked out to a user, a new entry in assigned_equipment is made, and the column is_assigned is set to 1. It can be 0 if it is later unassigned.

That being said, my query looks like this:
`SELECT * FROM hardware WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT object_id FROM assigned_equipment);`

I need a conditional statement that would add `WHERE is_assigned = 0` otherwise if there's an entry it will not list. Ideas?

Comment: So you want either `ID NOT IN (SELECT object_id FROM assigned_equipment)` or `is_assigned = 0`?

Comment: Surely the `is_assigned` column is redundant in a table called `assigned_equipment`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple extend the subquery to contain only assigned items:

```
SELECT * FROM hardware 
WHERE ID NOT IN 
  (SELECT object_id FROM assigned_equipment WHERE is_assigned = 1);
```

So, every matching id is NOT in the subselect - therefore unassigned.

Columns in the assignment table with `is_assigned=0` are no longer part of the subresult, and therefore part of your outer result.

Comment: Nailed it. I had it bass-ackwards. Thanks

Comment: You should accept the answer then in case people find this from google.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this without a JOIN so you should ditch the subselect.

```
SELECT 
    hardware.* 
FROM 
    hardware h 
LEFT JOIN 
    assigned_equipment e 
ON (e.object_id = h.id) 
WHERE 
    e.id IS NULL 
    OR 
    (e.is_assigned = 0 AND e.user_id = ?);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you take a semantic approach then the `is_assigned` column should not be required - as only assigned items should appear in the `assigned_equipment` table.

Which would make your query:

```
SELECT *
FROM `hardware`
WHERE `id` NOT IN (
    SELECT `object_id`
    FROM `assigned_equipment`
);
```

This of course means that when an item becomes unassigned you `DELETE` the row from the `assigned_equipment` table.

In my opinion this is better as it means you're not storing unnecessary data.

Comment: I would normally agree, but I was asked to keep a checkout history.